# Не получается делегировать событие mouseenter

Tags: javascript, события, таблицы

Задача: необходимо подсвечивать колонки таблицы при наведении.

Навешивать слушатель событий на каждую ячейку таблицы не вариант, их может быть значительно больше, слишком требовательно, сразу решил делегировать события.

Сделал с событием mouseover, работает, но оно "всплывает" и потому подсвечивание может прерываться при наведении на дочерние элементы. Взял событие "mouseenter", оно не всплывает, но с ним делегирование не работает и в консоли пишет "e.target.closest is not a function"

Прошу помочь, почему так получается, и как все-таки делегировать событие mouseenter
p.s большинство стилей убрал, но в основном, суть сохранил

```js
// часть кода без проблем и ошибок:
let bigTable = document.querySelector('.table-big');

if (bigTable) {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table-big__row');
  const tableBigRow = document.querySelector('.table-big__row');
  const tdsLength = tableBigRow.querySelectorAll('td').length;
  const tds = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
  let num = 0;
  for (td of tds) {
    td.setAttribute('data-tdNum', num);
    ++num;
    if (num == tdsLength) {
      num = 0;
    }
  }
}

// часть кода с проблемами и ошибками

// hight-light cell
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget) {
    if (e.relatedTarget.closest('._hight-light__cell')) {
      const cells = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
      for (cell of cells) {
        cell.classList.remove('_hover');
      }
    }
  }
 
  if (e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell')) {
    const hoverCell = e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell');
    const hoverCellNum = hoverCell.getAttribute('data-tdnum');
    if (hoverCell.classList.contains('_hover')) {
      return;
    } else {
      const cells = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
      for (cell of cells) {
        const cellsWithNum = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tdnum="${hoverCellNum}"]`);
        for (cellWithNum of cellsWithNum) {
          cellWithNum.classList.add('_hover');
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
._hight-light__cell._hover {
  background-color: #09AB3D;
  color: #fff;  
}
._hight-light__cell {
  transition: font-weight 0.3s ease 0s;
}
._hight-light__cell:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="pilmat-tables__table-and-btn">
          <div class="pilmat-tables__wrapper">
            <table class="pilmat-tables__table-big table-big">
              <tr class="pilmat-tables__main-row pilmat-tables__visible">
                <th class="pilmat-tables__head">ПИЛОМАТЕРИАЛЫ ОБРЕЗНЫЕ ЕСТЕСТВЕННОЙ ВЛАЖНОСТИ</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row light-blue pilmat-tables__visible">
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number">&#8470;</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name">наименование</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size">размер сечения, <br>мм</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade">сорт</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long">длина, м</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount"> 
                  кол-во шт в м<span class="goods__squared">3</span>
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price">цена, руб</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth">укажите количество</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost">стоимость, <br> руб</td> 
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del">добавить/ удалить</td>
              </tr>
              
              <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">1</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 100 х 6000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
                    <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
                      <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size1.webp" 
                      alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">66</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">33</div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">0,5</div>
                  </div>
                  
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td> 
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
  
              <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">2</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 150 х 6000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
                    <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
                      <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size2.webp" 
                      alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">44</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                  </div>
                  
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td> 
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-toggle__item"><span>шт</span>V</div>
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
  
              <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">3</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 50 х 150 х 6000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
                    <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
                      <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size3.webp" 
                      alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">22</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                  </div>
                  
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td> 
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">4</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 100 х 6000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
                    <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
                      <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size1.webp" 
                      alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">66</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">33</div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">0,5</div>
                  </div>
                  
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td> 
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
  
              <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">5</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 150 х 6000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
                    <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
                      <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size2.webp" 
                      alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">44</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                  </div>
                  
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td> 
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-toggle__item"><span>шт</span>V</div>
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
  
              <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">6</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 50 х 150 х 6000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
                    <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
                      <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size3.webp" 
                      alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">22</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                    <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
                  </div>
                  
                </td>
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td> 
                <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
                  <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="_more__btn-wrapper">
            <p class="_more__btn _tables__more-btn">ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЕ</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: При замене mouseover на mouseenter в консоли пишет "e.target.closest is not a function"

Comment: Добавляйте детали в сам вопрос, нажав на кнопку Править под вопросом

Comment: в приложенном сниппете ошибка не воспроизводитя

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов:

```js
// часть кода без проблем и ошибок:
let bigTable = document.querySelector('.table-big');

if (bigTable) {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table-big__row');
  const tableBigRow = document.querySelector('.table-big__row');
  const tdsLength = tableBigRow.querySelectorAll('td').length;
  const tds = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
  let num = 0;
  for (td of tds) {
    td.setAttribute('data-tdNum', num);
    ++num;
    if (num == tdsLength) {
      num = 0;
    }
  }
}

// часть кода с проблемами и ошибками

// hight-light cell
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget) {
    if (e.relatedTarget.closest('._hight-light__cell')) {
      const cells = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
      for (cell of cells) {
        cell.classList.remove('_hover');
      }
    }
  }

  if (e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell')) {
    const hoverCell = e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell');
    const hoverCellNum = hoverCell.getAttribute('data-tdnum');
    if (hoverCell.classList.contains('_hover')) {
      return;
    } else {
      const cells = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
      for (cell of cells) {
        const cellsWithNum = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tdnum="${hoverCellNum}"]`);
        for (cellWithNum of cellsWithNum) {
          cellWithNum.classList.add('_hover');
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.pilmat-tables__table-big{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

td{
   border: 1px solid grey;
}

._hight-light__cell._hover {
  background-color: #09AB3D;
  color: #fff;
}

._hight-light__cell {
  transition: font-weight 0.3s ease 0s;
}

._hight-light__cell:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="pilmat-tables__table-and-btn">
  <div class="pilmat-tables__wrapper">
    <table class="pilmat-tables__table-big table-big">
      <tr class="pilmat-tables__main-row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <th class="pilmat-tables__head">ПИЛОМАТЕРИАЛЫ ОБРЕЗНЫЕ ЕСТЕСТВЕННОЙ ВЛАЖНОСТИ</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row light-blue pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number">&#8470;</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name">наименование</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size">размер сечения, <br>мм</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade">сорт</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long">длина, м</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount">
          кол-во шт в м<span class="goods__squared">3</span>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price">цена, руб</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth">укажите количество</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost">стоимость, <br> руб</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del">добавить/ удалить</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">1</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 100 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size1.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">66</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">33</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">0,5</div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">2</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size2.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">44</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item"><span>шт</span>V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">3</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 50 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size3.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">22</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">4</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 100 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size1.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">66</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">33</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">0,5</div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">5</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size2.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">44</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item"><span>шт</span>V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 50 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size3.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">22</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="_more__btn-wrapper">
    <p class="_more__btn _tables__more-btn">ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЕ</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что у вас есть пустые места между ячейками. Когда на них наводится мышка вы не можете определить на какой колонке находится мышка. Предлагаю вам простой вариант: просто убрать эти пустоты добавив аттрибуты `border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` в тег `table`:

```js
// часть кода без проблем и ошибок:
let bigTable = document.querySelector('.table-big');

if (bigTable) {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table-big__row');
  const tableBigRow = document.querySelector('.table-big__row');
  const tdsLength = tableBigRow.querySelectorAll('td').length;
  const tds = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
  let num = 0;
  for (td of tds) {
    td.setAttribute('data-tdNum', num);
    ++num;
    if (num == tdsLength) {
      num = 0;
    }
  }
}

// часть кода с проблемами и ошибками

// hight-light cell
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget) {
    if (e.relatedTarget.closest('._hight-light__cell')) {
      const cells = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
      for (cell of cells) {
        cell.classList.remove('_hover');
      }
    }
  }

  if (e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell')) {
    const hoverCell = e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell');
    const hoverCellNum = hoverCell.getAttribute('data-tdnum');
    if (hoverCell.classList.contains('_hover')) {
      return;
    } else {
      const cells = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
      for (cell of cells) {
        const cellsWithNum = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tdnum="${hoverCellNum}"]`);
        for (cellWithNum of cellsWithNum) {
          cellWithNum.classList.add('_hover');
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
._hight-light__cell._hover {
  background-color: #09AB3D;
  color: #fff;
}

._hight-light__cell {
  transition: font-weight 0.3s ease 0s;
}

._hight-light__cell:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="pilmat-tables__table-and-btn">
  <div class="pilmat-tables__wrapper">
    <table class="pilmat-tables__table-big table-big" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr class="pilmat-tables__main-row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <th class="pilmat-tables__head">ПИЛОМАТЕРИАЛЫ ОБРЕЗНЫЕ ЕСТЕСТВЕННОЙ ВЛАЖНОСТИ</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row light-blue pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number">&#8470;</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name">наименование</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size">размер сечения, <br>мм</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade">сорт</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long">длина, м</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount">
          кол-во шт в м<span class="goods__squared">3</span>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price">цена, руб</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth">укажите количество</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost">стоимость, <br> руб</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del">добавить/ удалить</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">1</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 100 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size1.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">66</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">33</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">0,5</div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">2</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size2.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">44</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item"><span>шт</span>V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row pilmat-tables__visible">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">3</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 50 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size3.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">22</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">4</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 100 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size1.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">66</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">33</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">0,5</div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">5</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 25 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size2.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">44</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item"><span>шт</span>V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="table-big__row pilmat-tables__row">
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__number table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__name table-big__defult">доска обрезная <br> 50 х 150 х 6000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__size table-big__size-img table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-big__img-wrapper">
            <div class="table-big__img-wrapper-inner">
              <img src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pages_img/pilmat/pilmat-tables/section_size3.webp" alt="сечение" class="table-big__img _pb_img_max">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__grade table-big__defult">AB</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__long table-big__defult">6</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__amount table-big__defult">22</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__price table-big__defult">15 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__write-amounth write-amounth table-big__defult">
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item">шт</div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item">м<span class="goods__squared">3</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="write-amounth__item-wrapper">
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
            <div class="write-amounth__item"></div>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__total-cost table-big__defult">7 000</td>
        <td class="_hight-light__cell table-big__add-del table-toggle table-big__defult">
          <div class="table-toggle__item">V</div>
          <div class="table-toggle__item">X</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="_more__btn-wrapper">
    <p class="_more__btn _tables__more-btn">ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЕ</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, нашел решение
Я бросил попытку идти через mouseenter, и просто убирал класс _hover со всех элементов, а после вешал на наведенные

```js
// hight-light cell
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  if (e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell')) {
    const hoverCell = e.target.closest('._hight-light__cell');
    const hoverCellNum = hoverCell.getAttribute('data-tdnum');
    if (hoverCell.classList.contains('_hover')) {
      return;
    } else {
      const cells = document.querySelectorAll('._hight-light__cell');
      for (cell of cells) {
        cell.classList.remove('_hover');
      }
      const cellsWithNum = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tdnum="${hoverCellNum}"]`);
      for (cellWithNum of cellsWithNum) {
        cellWithNum.classList.add('_hover');
      }
    }
  }
})
```